# Child class can't call its parent's prototype method

Tags: javascript, inheritance, methods, call, prototype-programming

I'm learning JS prototypes.

From `Java` language point I expect,that `SpecificRectangle` object will have access to `area()` method,due to area() is the method of its parent(Rectangle class) prototype.

```
function Rectangle(w,h){
 this.width = w;
 this.height=h;
}
Rectangle.prototype.area = function(){return this.width*this.height}

function SpecificRectangle(w,h,angle){
  Rectangle.call(this,w,h);
  SpecificRectangle.prototype=new Rectangle();
}

var specrec = new SpecificRectangle(7,8,45);
```

All at all I can't call `area()` method on `SpecificRectangle` instance.
Standard JS error got:

```
TypeError: specrec.area is not a function
[Break On This Error] specrec.area()
```

What is the explanation and reason of such encapsulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly i don't know the exact reason but you need to set the prototype outside the constructor function:

```
function SpecificRectangle(w, h, angle) {
    Rectangle.call(this,w,h);
}

SpecificRectangle.prototype = new Rectangle();
SpecificRectangle.prototype.constructor = SpecificRectangle; // Otherwise instances of SpecificRectangle would have a constructor of Rectangle
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/5TSc6/).

---

**Edit** following the comment by @herby:

It seems indeed that the upper method could break the prototypal inheritance depending on how the super-class constructor is built (see [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2180-Your-Javascript-Constructor-Logic-May-Break-Prototypal-Inheritance.htm)).

A more robust solution is to use `Object.create` ([source](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2184-Object-create-Improves-Constructor-Based-Inheritance-In-Javascript-It-Doesn-t-Replace-It.htm) - thanks herby)

```
// in case Object.create does not exist
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function(o) {
        var F = function() {};
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}

function Rectangle(w, h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}
Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
    return this.width * this.height
}

function SpecificRectangle(w, h, angle) {
    Rectangle.call(this, w, h);
}

SpecificRectangle.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);
SpecificRectangle.prototype.constructor = SpecificRectangle;

var r = new SpecificRectangle(100, 50, 30);
alert(r.area());
```

Updated example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Jjzkc/)

Comment: You should not use `SpecificRectangle.prototype = new Rectangle()`. It works many times, but is, in principle, incorrect. If you have ES5, you should use `SpecificRectangle.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype)` instead, if you cannot guarantee ES5, you should define create like `function create(proto) { function f() {} f.prototype = proto; return new f(); }` and issue `SpecificRectangle.prototype = create(Rectangle.prototype)`. The issue is, prototype should not _be the initiailized instance_ of superclass, it should just inherit from that prototype without actually initializing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This has lead me to reading this [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2180-Your-Javascript-Constructor-Logic-May-Break-Prototypal-Inheritance.htm) about the problem you describe and this [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2184-Object-create-Improves-Constructor-Based-Inheritance-In-Javascript-It-Doesn-t-Replace-It.htm) on the Object.create (read the comments as well).

Answer (score 1):

You should copy base class prototype. Eg:

```
function Rectangle(w,h){
    this.width = w;
    this.height=h;
}
Rectangle.prototype.area = function(){return this.width*this.height}

function SpecificRectangle(w,h,angle){
    Rectangle.call(this,w,h);
}
function SpecificRectangleProto(){}
SpecificRectangleProto.prototype = Rectangle.prototype;
SpecificRectangle.prototype = new SpecificRectangleProto();

var specrec = new SpecificRectangle(7,8,45);
alert(specrec.area);
```

I suggest to extract extend method from some framework. For example ExtJS.
With such method you can extend class like this:

```
SpecificRectangle = extend(Rectangle, {
    constructor: function(w,h,angle){
        SpecificRectangle.superclass.constructor.call(this,w,h);
    }
});
```

Comment: Never do this: `SpecificRectangle.prototype = {};
for (var i in Rectangle.prototype) {
    SpecificRectangle.prototype[i] = Rectangle.prototype[i];
}
`! You should inherit, not mix in.

Comment: @herby On the second thought i see the problem with this. If the original prototype is changed, the change won't propagate to the subclasses. Probably it's not often used, but visualizes problem.